# navigation bar scroll when clicked

Tags: html

```
<div class="navbar">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
       <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">company name</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
      <li><a href="#" style="color:white;">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color:white;">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a class="portfolio-scroll" href="#" style="color:white;" id="contact-nav">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

i wanted to make my navbar when one of the option in the navbar is clicked the page would scroll to that specific section in the page, for example when i click contact on my navbar the page would scroll down to the contact section in the same page

how to make something like that, can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this easily using [HTML anchors](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-anchor-link.htm).

Give your section, say "About", an ID:

```
<h1 id="about">About</h1>
```

And then change your anchor's link:

```
<a href="#about" style="color:white;">About</a>
```

And when you click the anchor, it will automatically scroll to the correct place. The best thing about this is that it requires **no** javascript, and is supported in every browser.

**Note**: You also have your end tags switched around - `</div>` and `</nav>` are in the wrong order.

Comment: Good to hear @user45938 - if this works for you, would you mind accepting the answer? :)

Comment: how to make it scroll animated to the point rather than suddenly showing it

Comment: If you want to make the scroll animated, Just add html{scroll-behavior:smooth} in your CSS!

Answer (score 6):

You can use ids for scrolling.

Simply, put the id in like this

```
   <div id="about"></div>
```

then in a href you can do something like this,

```
   <a href="#about">Click to scroll</a>
```

Also, for avoiding the sudden pop and for a smooth transition effect you can write the following in css.

```
   html{
     scroll-behavior: smooth;;
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use javascript for that. Here is my example.

```js
$("a").click(function(){
  var pageId = $(this).attr("data-page");
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#"+pageId).offset().top }, 1000);
});
```

```css
div.page {
  min-height:1000px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
       <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">company name</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
      <li><a href="#" style="color:blue;" data-page="about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color:blue;" data-page="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a class="portfolio-scroll" href="#" style="color:blue;" id="contact-nav" data-page="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    
    <div class="page" id="about"><h1>About</h1></div>
    <div class="page" id="portfolio"><h1>Portfolio</h1></div>
    <div class="page" id="contact"><h1>Contact</h1></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i'll try this one later because i haven't learned javascript yetso  for now i'm gonna use the anchor method

Comment: What if we had to navigate from another page?